# std::vector compiler error ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, clion, linkage

I'm trying to use [libnormaliz](https://github.com/Normaliz/Normaliz) library in Clion. However, it is directly linked from its path i.e. `/Users/soner/Downloads/normaliz-3.4.0/source/libnormaliz` by CMake `include_directories(/Users/soner/Downloads/normaliz-3.4.0/source/libnormaliz)`
. I've downloaded its [released version](https://github.com/Normaliz/Normaliz/releases). But the error appears when run,

With Clang specification,

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "libnormaliz::Cone<int>::Cone(libnormaliz::Type::InputType, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "libnormaliz::Cone<int>::~Cone()", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::allocate(unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
      std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > >::allocate(unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
  "std::logic_error::logic_error(char const*)", referenced from:
      std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::allocate(unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
      std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > >::allocate(unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
  "std::length_error::~length_error()", referenced from:
      std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::allocate(unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
      std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > >::allocate(unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in main.cpp.o
  "typeinfo for std::length_error", referenced from:
      std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::allocate(unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
      std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > >::allocate(unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
  "vtable for std::length_error", referenced from:
      std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::allocate(unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
      std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > >::allocate(unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
      std::__1::__vector_base<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::~__vector_base() in main.cpp.o
      std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > >::~__vector_base() in main.cpp.o
  "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::allocate(unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
      std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > >::allocate(unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
  "___cxa_allocate_exception", referenced from:
      std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::allocate(unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
      std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > >::allocate(unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in main.cpp.o
  "___cxa_free_exception", referenced from:
      std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::allocate(unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
      std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > >::allocate(unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
  "___cxa_throw", referenced from:
      std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::allocate(unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
      std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > >::allocate(unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
      std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::allocate(unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
      std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > >::allocate(unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
      std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::vector(std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > const&) in main.cpp.o
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Without Clang specification,

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "libnormaliz::Cone<int>::Cone(libnormaliz::Type::InputType, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "libnormaliz::Cone<int>::~Cone()", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

The code,

```
#include <libnormaliz/libnormaliz.h>
#include <libnormaliz/cone.h>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector <int> > data { {1,1,1}, {2,2,2} };

    libnormaliz::Type::InputType type = libnormaliz::Type::cone;
    /* runs well up to here */
    libnormaliz::Cone<int> MyCone = libnormaliz::Cone<int>(type, data);

    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(untitled2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(LIB_NORMALIZ_PATH /Users/soner/Downloads/normaliz-3.4.0/source/libnormaliz)

find_library(
        LIB_NORMALIZ
        libnormaliz
        PATHS
        ${LIB_NORMALIZ_PATH}
)

if (NOT FOUND_LIB_NORMALIZ)
    message(SEND_ERROR "Unable to find libnormaliz")
endif()

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(untitled2 ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(untitled2 ${LIB_NORMALIZ})
target_include_directories(untitled2 PUBLIC ${LIB_NORMALIZ_PATH})
```

Its output,

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (message):
  Unable to find libnormaliz


CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
LIB_NORMALIZ
    linked by target "untitled2" in directory /Users/soner/CLionProjects/untitled2
```

[image] It is from its [reference manual](https://github.com/Normaliz/Normaliz/blob/master/doc/Normaliz.pdf).

Path,
[image]

Comment: Are you linking in the library?

Comment: yes @SteveLorimer

Comment: you haven't - you need to use [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html)

Comment: include_directories does not link the library, it only adds a directory to the search path for headers. You need to use link_libraries. Or better, use target_link_libraries to link specifically to your app.

Comment: @snr please update your question to show how you are linking against the lirbary

Comment: @snr your CMakeLists shows you're *finding* the library, but once found you're not *linking* it

Answer (score 0):

You're not linking against `libnormaliz`

You need to configure cmake to link the library.

The first step is telling cmake how to find the library, for which you use [`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html)

```
find_library(
    LIB_NORMALIZ
    libnormaliz
    PATHS
        /Users/soner/Downloads/normaliz-3.4.0/source/libnormaliz
    )
```

You can verify if cmake was able to find it:

```
if (NOT FOUND_LIB_NORMALIZ)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Unable to find libnormaliz")
endif()
```

Once cmake has found the library, you then need to link it to your target using [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html)

```
target_link_libraries(untitled2 ${LIB_NORMALIZ})
```

Your `CMakeLists.txt` should look something like the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(untitled2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(LIB_NORMALIZ_PATH /Users/soner/Downloads/normaliz-3.4.0/source/libnormaliz)

find_library(
    LIB_NORMALIZ
    libnormaliz
    PATHS
        ${LIB_NORMALIZ_PATH}
    )

if (NOT FOUND_LIB_NORMALIZ)
    message(SEND_ERROR "Unable to find libnormaliz")
endif()

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(untitled2 ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(untitled2 ${LIB_NORMALIZ})
target_include_directories(untitled2 PUBLIC ${LIB_NORMALIZ_PATH})
```

(Note I've changed `include_directories` to `target_include_directories` as this is idiomatic of modern cmake)

Comment: `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (if):
  if given arguments:

    "not" "FOUND_LIB_NORMALIX"

  Unknown arguments specified` for checking when I write it on CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @snr try capital NOT?

Comment: if (NOT FOUND_LIB_NORMALIX) or if (NOT FOUND_LIB_NORMALIZ)? I getnot found error for both of them. But the directory includes headers and cpp files, I have edited the question.

Comment: @snr have you actually built the library? It's one thing downloading the libnormaliz source, but you need to then build it. Have you followed the **Building Normaliz yourself** instructions on the [github page](https://github.com/Normaliz/Normaliz)?

Comment: Sir, firstly I really thank you for your helping. However, I tried it more than 20 times. It needs additional libraries and the additional libraries also need additional ones as far as I see. I have installed soplex for SCIP but it gives still errors like,

Comment: checking contents of scipoptsuite source directory... Found scipoptsuite in /Users/soner/Documents/scip/scip-4.0.1

 Found short link /Users/soner/Documents/scip/scip-4.0.1 

checking whether SCIP headers and library are available... no

configure: Cone decomposition with SCIP integer programming solver will not be available because the SCIP library was not found

checking whether CoCoALib headers and library are available... no

configure: nmzIntegrate will not be built because CoCoALib was not found

Comment: **Wheras, cocoa and scip has been built. But still get the errors. I have been trying to use the library for 2 weeks.** So, after too many headaches I thought the library is already built because I have released version. Did I think wrong? But still same error in both ways.

Comment: I'm afraid yes, I believe you did think wrong. This is how open source works I'm afraid - you need to read the github page and find out the dependencies required. Then using either a package manager like [homebrew](https://brew.sh/), or if not available there, the source for each dependency, obtain built versions of those dependencies, and so on and so forth, up the chain, until you have built versions of all dependencies, and then you can build this library.